# How to conditionally pass args to remote-exec in terraform

Tags: bash, terraform

```
 provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x run-image.sh",
      "./run-image.sh var.env_name == 'dev' ? var.dev_image_version : var.image_version"
    ]
  }
```

How do I conditonally pass args to `sh` script above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "chmod +x run-image.sh",
    "./run-image.sh ${var.env_name == 'dev' ? var.dev_image_version : var.image_version}"
  ]
}
```

you can use braces for variables  and operators